# Show that there exist a function $\varphi\in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $f(\varphi)>0$ .

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $a\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with $a^{+}\neq 0$, here $a^{+}=\max\{a(x),0\}$. Given
$$ f(u)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{a(x)u^{2}(x)a(y)u^{2}(y)}{|x-y|^{N-2}}dxdy,~~\forall u\in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N).$$
Show that there exist a function $\varphi\in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $f(\varphi)>0$.

I tried to assume that for all  $\varphi\in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $f(\varphi)\leq 0$, but I can't find a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. Take 
$$a(x) = \begin{cases} 1,\ x=0 \ \\ 0, \ x\neq 0\end{cases}$$
Then $a^+ = 1$, but $f(\phi) = 0$ for any $\phi \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. However if you assume that $a > C > 0$ on some set of positive measure $A \subset \mathbb{R}^N$. Then let $\phi = \chi_A$, where  $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$. Then
$$f(\phi) = \int_A\int_A \frac{a(x)a(y)}{|x-y|^{N-2}}dydx > C \int_A \int_{A}\frac{1}{|x-y|^{N-2}}dydx >0$$
Note that the Hilbert transform is well defined on $C^1_c$, so the above integral converges.

Comment: In particular, if you replace the condition $a^+ \neq 0$ with the more natural $||a||_{\infty} \neq 0$, then the statement is true.